# Hibernate saving records in random order

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am using Hibernate in my application and at one place, I am trying to save multiple records into the same table at once. These records are child records referring to a parent( a many-to-one relation from child to parent). The parent and the child records are saved at once. Following is the code.

```
Beats beats = new Beats();

HashSet<BeatMembers> beatMembersSet = new HashSet<BeatMembers>();
String[] membersArray = beatMembers.split(",");

for (int i = 0; i < membersArray.length; i++) {
    BeatMembers member = new BeatMembers();
    member.setMemberName(membersArray[i]);
    member.setBeats(beats);
    beatMembersSet.add(member);
}

beats.setBeatMemberses(beatMembersSet);
session.save(beats);
```

As you can see, I am splitting a string based on ',' and saving the resulting array into multiple records in the database.

My problem is that the order in which the records are being saved is not same as the order in which they are created. Is there a way to fix this?

I am using hibernate 4.3.8 with MySQL 5.6 and running on Java 1.7.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You store your members in a HashSet. A HashSet does not preserve the order of its members. Use a LinkedHashSet or a List instead.

Comment: ... or a `LinkedList` instead. Otherwise the same will happen.